# How to unit test ui-route in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a simple directive that builds this kind of html:

```
<div class='snapshots-feeds-toggle-box'>
    <button ui-sref='feeds' class='state-toggle-btn' ui-sref-active='active-state'>Feeds</button>
    <button ui-sref='snapshots' class='state-toggle-btn' ui-sref-active='active-state'>Snapshots</button>
</div>
```

I want to unit test it (karma+jasmine) as follows:

I just want to check if i put a state of feeds, the button is 'active', How should i procced:

var scope,compile;

```
beforeEach(module('feedsSnapshotsApp'));
beforeEach(module('directives'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope,$compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;
...
   scope.state = 'feeds' //?
it('should check if state is active',function(){
     //What is the check that i can do here?
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your question again: "How to unit test `ui-route` in angular js"

Why would you do that? That behavior you want to test out is already tested in `ui-router` so you don't need to re-test something that is already tested somewhere else. Focus on what you directive has to provide and test it.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, for example in my case i'm using a directive which depends on "ui-router" (states), i'm facing issues where I couldn't able to click a div with `ui-sref`, the state doesn't change while clicking!

Comment: That answer his question, not your question.